# How to make custom tooltip in SfCartesianChart?

Tags: flutter, dart, syncfusion

I have tooltip that looks like this:[image]

But I want to customize it to this:

[image]

How can I do this?

This is my code:

```
void initState() {
    _tooltipBehavior = TooltipBehavior(
      enable: true,
      color: Colors.transparent,
      header: "",
      duration: 0,
      format: "point.y%\npoint.x",
      canShowMarker: false,
      textAlignment: ChartAlignment.center
      // builder: (data, point, series, pointIndex, seriesIndex) {
      //   return Container(
      //     child: Text("data: point.y"),
      //   );
      // },
    );
    super.initState();
  }

SfCartesianChart(
  plotAreaBorderWidth: 0, // X top line
  plotAreaBorderColor: Colors.white24,
  tooltipBehavior: _tooltipBehavior,
  primaryXAxis: DateTimeAxis(
    majorTickLines: const MajorTickLines(width: 0), // Little sticks below X line
    majorGridLines: const MajorGridLines(
      width: 0.5,
      color: Colors.transparent,
    ),
    axisLine: const AxisLine( // X bottom line
      color: Colors.white24,
      dashArray: <double>[5,5]
    ),
  ),
  primaryYAxis: NumericAxis(
    majorGridLines: const MajorGridLines(width: 1, color: Colors.white24, dashArray: <double>[5, 5]),
    majorTickLines: const MajorTickLines(width: 0), // Little sticks on left side
    axisLine: const AxisLine(
      color: Colors.transparent, // Y left line
      dashArray: <double>[5,5]
    ),
    minimum: 0,
    maximum: 100,
  ),
)
```

And I met a bug with displation of point.y, When I move a mouse below blue line then it shows me => point.y%. But when I move only on blue line then everything works fine, it shows me 54$. How can I fix that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**#Query 1: How can I do this?**

The requirement can be achieved with the help of [TrackballBehavior](https://pub.dev/documentation/syncfusion_flutter_charts/latest/charts/TrackballBehavior-class.html) in the chart and using its [builder](https://pub.dev/documentation/syncfusion_flutter_charts/latest/charts/TrackballBehavior/builder.html) property and show the customizable widget. The [TrackballBehavior](https://pub.dev/documentation/syncfusion_flutter_charts/latest/charts/TrackballBehavior-class.html) supports the marker for the currently activated data point and has a line support too. So, you can show the marker and line for the presently activated point with the help of [markerSettings](https://pub.dev/documentation/syncfusion_flutter_charts/latest/charts/TrackballBehavior/markerSettings.html) property and place the custom widget with the help of the [tooltipAlignment](https://pub.dev/documentation/syncfusion_flutter_charts/latest/charts/TrackballBehavior/tooltipAlignment.html) of [TrackballBehavior](https://pub.dev/documentation/syncfusion_flutter_charts/latest/charts/TrackballBehavior-class.html). We have shared the code snippet below for your reference.

[image]

Code snippet:

```dart
import 'dart:math';
import 'package:intl/intl.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:syncfusion_flutter_charts/charts.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(const MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: const MyHomePage(title: 'Flutter Demo Home Page'),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyHomePage({super.key, required this.title});

  final String title;

  @override
  State<MyHomePage> createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  late List<ChartData> chartData;

  @override
  void initState() {
    chartData = [
      ChartData(DateTime(2022, 12, 01, 09, 12), 50),
      ChartData(DateTime(2022, 12, 01, 09, 13), 45),
      ChartData(DateTime(2022, 12, 01, 09, 14), 54),
      ChartData(DateTime(2022, 12, 01, 09, 15), 51),
      ChartData(DateTime(2022, 12, 01, 09, 16), 53),
      ChartData(DateTime(2022, 12, 01, 09, 17), 49),
      ChartData(DateTime(2022, 12, 01, 09, 18), 54),
      ChartData(DateTime(2022, 12, 01, 09, 19), 45),
      ChartData(DateTime(2022, 12, 01, 09, 20), 30),
      ChartData(DateTime(2022, 12, 01, 09, 21), 48),
      ChartData(DateTime(2022, 12, 01, 09, 22), 65),
      ChartData(DateTime(2022, 12, 01, 09, 23), 63),
      ChartData(DateTime(2022, 12, 01, 09, 24), 71),
      ChartData(DateTime(2022, 12, 01, 09, 25), 48),
      ChartData(DateTime(2022, 12, 01, 09, 26), 51),
      ChartData(DateTime(2022, 12, 01, 09, 27), 49),
    ];
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: SfCartesianChart(
        trackballBehavior: TrackballBehavior(
            enable: true,
            markerSettings: const TrackballMarkerSettings(
                height: 10,
                width: 10,
                markerVisibility: TrackballVisibilityMode.visible,
                borderColor: Colors.black,
                borderWidth: 4,
                color: Colors.blue),
            activationMode: ActivationMode.singleTap,
            builder: (context, trackballDetails) {
              return SizedBox(
                height: 200,
                child: Column(
                  crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                  children: [
                    Text(
                      "${trackballDetails.groupingModeInfo!.points[0].y}%",
                      textAlign: TextAlign.left,
                      style: const TextStyle(color: Colors.white, fontSize: 20),
                    ),
                    const Padding(padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 5)),
                    Text(
                      DateFormat('hh:mm').format(
                          trackballDetails.groupingModeInfo!.points[0].x),
                      textAlign: TextAlign.left,
                      style: const TextStyle(
                        color: Colors.white,
                        fontSize: 10,
                      ),
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
              );
            },
            tooltipDisplayMode: TrackballDisplayMode.groupAllPoints,
            tooltipAlignment: ChartAlignment.near),
        backgroundColor: Colors.black,
        plotAreaBorderWidth: 0, // X top line
        plotAreaBorderColor: Colors.white24,
        primaryXAxis: DateTimeAxis(
          majorTickLines:
              const MajorTickLines(width: 0), // Little sticks below X line
          majorGridLines: const MajorGridLines(
            width: 0.5,
            color: Colors.transparent,
          ),
          axisLine: const AxisLine(
              // X bottom line
              color: Colors.white24,
              dashArray: <double>[5, 5]),
        ),
        primaryYAxis: NumericAxis(
          interval: 50,
          majorGridLines: const MajorGridLines(
              width: 1, color: Colors.white24, dashArray: <double>[5, 5]),
          majorTickLines:
              const MajorTickLines(width: 0), // Little sticks on left side
          axisLine: const AxisLine(color: Colors.transparent, // Y left line
              dashArray: <double>[5, 5]),
          minimum: 0,
          maximum: 100,
        ),
        series: <ChartSeries<ChartData, DateTime>>[
          AreaSeries(
              borderColor: Colors.blue,
              borderWidth: 3,
              gradient: LinearGradient(colors: [
                Colors.blue.withOpacity(0.4),
                Colors.blue.withOpacity(0.2),
                Colors.blue.withOpacity(0.1)
              ], stops: const [
                0.1,
                0.3,
                0.6
              ], begin: Alignment.topCenter, end: Alignment.bottomCenter),
              dataSource: chartData,
              xValueMapper: (ChartData data, _) => data.x,
              yValueMapper: (ChartData data, _) => data.y)
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}

class ChartData {
  final DateTime x;
  final num y;

  ChartData(this.x, this.y);
}
```

**#Query 2 : I met a bug with displation of point.y, When I move a mouse below blue line then it shows me => point.y%.**

Based on the provided code snippet, you have returned the Text widget with the string value point.y inside a text widget, that is why it shows the point.y text. Otherwise, it won't show the point.y value in the tooltip, we have also ensured this and no issue gets reproduced.

Answer (score 0):

You can follow this tutorial by the devs to understand how to customize the chart tooltip:

https://help.syncfusion.com/flutter/cartesian-charts/tooltip

You basically need to use the `builder` method of `TooltipBehavior`.

Comment: I tried to use builder but id doesn't work properly.. When I try to call "${point.y}" inside Text, then it returns me an error: RangeError (index): Invalid value: Valid value range is empty: 4